# How get JSON data while in splash view in Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, splash-screen, android-handler

Here I try to make a app.
First it shows a home page.It will display 2 sec.

Here is the code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int secondsDelayed = 3;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SocondActivity.class));
                    finish();
            }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);  
}
}
```

Then my second activity want to show a splash view until json string download from the rest service.

Here is my code....

```
public class SocondActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "SocondActivity";

    //please assume my url is OK
    private static String url = "my url";

    private String jsonStr;

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);




        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                new GetContacts().execute();
                Log.d(TAG,jsonStr);

                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SocondActivity.this,
                        ThirdActivity.class);
                SocondActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SocondActivity.this.finish();

            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //please assume that my Server Handler class is working fine
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Then I got this error......

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Because the `jsonStr` was empty....
Why is that ??

Here is my `R.layout.splash_screen`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar_50" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please tell me Is this method is correct and what should I change to make this correct ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race case. You need to do something like this.

Instead of utilizing a handler in onCreate like you are below (which is only serving to create a layer of complexity that isn't functioning like you expect)

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GetContacts().execute();
            Log.d(TAG,jsonStr);

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SocondActivity.this,
                    ThirdActivity.class);
            SocondActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SocondActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
```

Just call this in your onCreate()

```
new GetContacts().execute();
```

And in your AsyncTask, override the method onPostExecute like so

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Void voidParam){
    Log.d(TAG,jsonStr);

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SocondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
    SocondActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    SocondActivity.this.finish();
}
```

This will tell your app that you want to execute the AsyncTask, and when you are done (*and only when you are done*) you want to launch your next Activity. This removes the race case as well as the need for a handler/runnable.

Comment: Then I got this error in logcat 'java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()' @zgc7009
What should I do??

Comment: @NoughT I am going to assume you are trying to perform an operation during `jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);` that requires the main thread. What exactly are you trying to do? Volley will likely help you for what you are trying to do, and all you have to do is add listeners from volley's framework to trigger your next activity.

Comment: Here is my app flow. First show the home page. it will show 2 sec.
Then I want to show splash view. I want to show that splash view until that I download the json string from the server.
Then next activity will be show that json string in a list view. I am stuck in the splash view stage.
Can you help me??

Comment: With your code and additional search, I did that.
Thanks @zgc7009